# Best Pratices api call for mobile

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I begining with react-native to developp an application with firebase.
I want to know best pratices for mobile.

I have a list of products. The user can check is he like the element or not.
My question is if the user change of view and the display again the list, the best pratices is :

1. make call for the list
2. keep the list in the storage ( redux ) and update list and remake call api if the user start the app.

It's really different between mobile & web so ..
Thanks

Comment: Don't think of it as a difference between mobile and web. Think about it as "is there internet"? Instead of two problems you now only have one but, sadly, a question still a little too broad for this site.

Comment: Why not both? First you make the changes in your redux store, updating the state and then you make a call to the API in the background.

Comment: Andy: I think there is a difference for me, because I can make call with bad connexion and wait long long time to display a list ... or not connexion ^^  ( I imagine )
kapobajza: you said: I can make call api one time ( start app ) for a list and update list in store.   It's beter ?

Comment: I highly recommend you to read and use react-query, you will get a solution and broader perspective on this.